# How to send ES configurations use spark-submit?

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, spark-submit

How to send es configurations use spark-submit command like doing in hive?
 
Example:
`spark-submit
  ...
  --files hive-site.xml 
  --jars ...`

Then I can access hive tables use spark SQL,
I want to do similar things using ES, any hints?

Answer (score 0):

```
spark-submit --class Main --properties-file spark.conf
```